# Wamp localhost not calling all my includes

Tags: php, directory, include, localhost, wamp

I'm trying to break down my index.php into a individual blocks so I can edit one and it'll change across all of the pages in my website.

```
<html>
<?php include('includes/head.php'); ?>
<body>
    <? include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
    <div id="container">
        <? include 'includes/aside.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I run this through localhost the head and footer are being called but the header and aside files are being ignored.

[inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCSNf.png)

When I upload the file to my webhost the page loads fine with all the includes, so I figure its something to do with the localhost? The files header.php and aside.php do exist in the includes folder.

Comment: I'm going to assume that your head.php is pretty vital to your application. So it should therefore be required_once. Secondly, try echo the full path to the browser and see if your head.php actually live in that location.

Comment: youre using php shorttags in some of your code.. are you sure theyre enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You have typo mistake

Change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: I feel like an idiot haha thats been the problem for over a day now! thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps and try again:

As you have used `<? ?>` PHP short tags so please make sure that PHP short tags are enabled in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) file:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

And restart your Apache server.

Secondly, make sure that the path of your .php files is correct. Sometimes the current directory isn't what you expect it to be, such as when you include a file from an included file.
I like to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` on my includes so that I can always reference them absolutely from the root of my site:

```
<?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/somfolder/yourfile.php");        
?>
```

If your includes directory is above your document root, you can use `..` to still reference from the root.

Comment: In Windows, found this by click Wamp icon in taskbar :: PHP :: PHP Settings :: short open tag.